# hibernate wrongly converts query for jsonb field

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I have a jsonb field in which I have stored a key , value mapping in the db.
Not I want to make a query where given a text I want to know if a key exist which is like the text.
example the key in db is 'abc_def' and I have the text 'abc' so the query should return the record.

I have written a query for it:

`String sql = select * from table where (attrs->>'data')::jsonb::text like :queryKeyEspCorpCompany and status = 'ENABLED'`

queryKeyEspCorpCompany is passed a a param.
but when hibernate actually run the query it returns like so (in logs) and return error:

`select * from table where '(attrs->>'data')':jsonb:text like ? and status = 'ENABLED'`

error is where the "::" before jsonb is getting converted to ":".

Can someone help why this is happening ?

Comment: In PostgreSQL also there is an option to write native sql query. We are using postgress but query are written in sql

Comment: Maybe `:jsonb` is treated as named parameter? try to quote both colon chars... like `.. (attrs->>'data')\:\:jsonb\:\:text like ..`

Comment: This does'nt work, in sql query string escape char are not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character `:` needs to be escaped:

```
String sql = "select * from table where (attrs->>'data')\\:\\:jsonb\\:\\:text like ?1 and status = 'ENABLED'";
```

Because it's a native query, you have to use Postgres parameter placements syntax: `?1`, `?2`,...

Example:

```
session.createSQLQuery(sql).setParameter(1, "abc_def").getResultList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing but hibernate is converting the "::" to ":" and throwing error

Comment: Then use `cast(... as jsonb)` instead.